# How can I disable these URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

In Drupal 7, the following URLs show the same node.

- http://www.example.com/node/5
- http://www.example.com/node/5/randomtext1
- http://www.example.com/node/5/randomtext2
- http://www.example.com/node/5/randomtext3

This doesn't happen in Drupal 8.

How can those URLs be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users try to access a path that doesn't exist, for example /node/5/random-text-2, Drupal will show the parent page. More exactly, it will show the page for the first of the following paths that exists. (*%* is the wildcard character, used for paths defined from modules.)

- node/5/%
- node/%/random-text-2
- node/%/%
- node/5
- node/%
- node

Normally, Drupal would show the page for node/5 (which is considered the parent page for node/5/random-text-2), but when a module defines a page for node/%/%, Drupal will instead show that page.

A module could add a `hook_menu()` implementation similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['node/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

`mymodule_page()` could just show a 404 or a 403 error.

```php
function mymodule_page() {
  // Return a 404 error.
  return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

This would stop Drupal from showing a node page every time users access a path like node/[node-id]/[random-string], where the random string doesn't match with any menu defined from any module. (For example, if *[random-string]* is equal to *edit*, Drupal will show the node edit form.)

Returning a 403 error is simpler. Using the following hook implementation, a module would get that without writing much code (except eventually an empty function for the page callback).

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['node/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'access callback' => FALSE,
  );

  return $items;
}
```